# Epoch class functionality

Tags: javascript, unix, epoch

I am trying to make JavaScript code where I can put a `<span class="epoch>(unix timestamp)</span>` and it will set it to the timestamp in the user's timezone.

So far I have this code:

```
let epoch = document.getElementsByClassName("epoch");
for (var i = 0; i < epoch.length; i++) {
    let d = new Date(parseInt(epoch.item(i))).toDateString({ weekday: 'long', year: 'numeric', month: 'short', day: 'numeric' });
    epoch.item(i).innerText = d;
}
```

I tried replacing `epoch.item(i).innerText = d;` with `alert(d);` but that still didn't work.

HTML (not full version but still has the same things):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Mesure73L</title>
  <link href="index.css?v=1" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="index.js?v=1" defer></script>
  <script src="https://mesure.x10.mx/public_assets/main.js?v=1" defer></script>
  <script id="mobile_navbar"></script>
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.png">
</head>

<body>
  <script id="replace_with_navbar" src="https://mesure.x10.mx/public_assets/navbar.js?v=1"></script>
  <div id="content">
    <p><span id="epoch">1700523189</span></p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `document.getElementByClassName` is undefined.  Did you mean `document.getElementsByClassName`?  Please copy and paste your code as you wrote it.

Comment: @danronmoon I had that in my original code, but it didn't save.

Comment: Please folks, use proper terminology.  An "epoch" refers only to the value associated with the timestamp value of `0`.  The Unix epoch happens to be `1970-01-01T00:00:00Z`, so if you are referring to timestamps based on the Unix epoch, those are "Unix Timestamps", not "epochs" or "epoch timestamps".  There are actually many different epochs that have been used for timestamps in computing.  The Unix epoch is not the only one.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(computing)#Notable_epoch_dates_in_computing

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Original Answer

There are a few things to correct and improve in your JavaScript code to achieve the functionality you're looking for.

1. **Typo in `getElementsByClassName`**: The method name should be `getElementsByClassName` (plural) instead of `getElementByClassName` (singular).
2. **Parsing the Timestamp**: The `parseInt` function should be called with the `innerText` of the `epoch` element to convert the epoch timestamp string to a number.
3. **Date Formatting**: The `toDateString` method doesn't accept any arguments. To format the date, you should use `toLocaleDateString` instead, which allows specifying formatting options.
4. You are using an ID as epoch and calling a Class.

```js
let epochs = document.getElementsByClassName("epoch");
for (var i = 0; i < epochs.length; i++) {
    let timestamp = parseInt(epochs[i].innerText, 10);
    let date = new Date(timestamp * 1000); // Convert to milliseconds
    let formattedDate = date.toLocaleDateString(undefined, { 
        weekday: 'long', 
        year: 'numeric', 
        month: 'short', 
        day: 'numeric', 
        hour: '2-digit', 
        minute: '2-digit', 
        second: '2-digit', 
        timeZoneName: 'short' 
    });
    epochs[i].innerText = formattedDate;
}
```

#### Explanation:

- `getElementsByClassName("epoch")` returns a live HTMLCollection of found elements with the class name "epoch".
- `parseInt(epochs[i].innerText, 10)` parses the inner text of each element as an integer in base 10 (epoch timestamp).
- `new Date(timestamp * 1000)` creates a new Date object from the epoch timestamp. Epoch time is in seconds, but JavaScript's Date object constructor requires milliseconds, hence the multiplication by 1000.
- `toLocaleDateString(undefined, {...})` formats the date according to the user's local settings (`undefined` makes it use the user's locale). The options object specifies how various parts of the date should be represented.
- Finally, `epochs[i].innerText = formattedDate` replaces the inner text of each span with the formatted date string.

JSFiddle Link: https://jsfiddle.net/Termato/d1ytopuq/1/

---

#### Updated:

Use the following code:

```
<span class="epoch">(epoch timestamp)</span>
```

And then for the JavaScript:

```
 window.onload = function() {
    // Get the current timestamp in seconds
    var milliseconds = new Date().getTime();

    // Create a Date object from the current timestamp
    let date = new Date(milliseconds * 1000);

    // Find the span element and set its content
    let epochSpan = document.querySelector('.epoch');
    if (epochSpan) {
        epochSpan.innerText = date;
    }
};
```

You can see the JSFiddle Here: https://jsfiddle.net/Termato/hr7ytf1p/5/

In your question, you reference a Class but in your code epoch is an ID. This wont work. Either make `<span class="epoch">` OR change the javascript to target the ID: `document.querySelector('#epoch');`

See this JS Fiddle for example: https://jsfiddle.net/Termato/zmcaoxb9/2/

Comment: I copied that code and put it in my JS file but it still doesn't work

Comment: Can you post your HTML in your question?

Comment: I edited my message to include HTML

Comment: I made an example with a JSFiddle for you. Should work much better. Make sure to check all quotations and class spellings, too.

Comment: It still doesn't work

Comment: Click on the JS Fiddle and see the working example: https://jsfiddle.net/Termato/hr7ytf1p/5/

If it's not working, is your javascript loading correctly?

Comment: @Mesure73L Please see updated answer.

Comment: My javascript is loaded correctly, I know this because I replaced all of it with an `alert('loaded');`

Comment: Read the updated answer, please. `<span id="epoch">1700523189</span>` needs to be `<span class="epoch">1700523189</span>`

Comment: I'm going off of your first answer because it solves my problem better, but it's giving the wrong time, and if I have multiple epoch timestamps on one page it shows in CST and CDT, instead of just CST.

Comment: Interesting, I tried it here and I got the right timezone (EST). I added the original answer for reference with a JSFiddle.

Comment: I'm saving the JS in a separate file and importing it by link, is that a problem? I figured out the wrong time thing but it still displays in different time zones when I have multiple timestamps. Your JSFiddle only has one timestamp, my problem is with 2.

Comment: @Mesure73L - That is how it is supposed to work.  If the local time zone has daylight saving time, then for timestamps when it is applicable the time zone offset and abbreviation should use daylight time, and for timestamps when it is not applicable it should use standard time.

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint if I have 2 timestamps in one page, one of them shows as CST (correct) and the other shows as CDT (incorrect).

Comment: You're confusing a time zone (a system of local timekeeping in a region) with a specific time zone offset and its colloquial abbreviation.  For example, the Central time zone in the USA (id: `America/Chicago`), uses Central Standard Time (UTC-6) during parts of the year, and Central Daylight Time (UTC-5) during the other parts of the year.  The overall time zone is Central Time.  Whether to use CST or CDT depends on the specific date and time.  That's why you see two different abbreviations on the same page.  The ones showing CDT are when daylight saving time is in effect.

Comment: See also [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info) for more clarification.  Especially pay attention to the section titled "Time Zone != Offset".  You might also be interested in [a visual representation](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/usa/chicago).  Thanks.

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint sorry for the late reply. I would like it to display in the correct time zone offset. so if the user is in CST (UTC-6) i want it to display in CST, if the user is in CDT (UTC-5) i want it to display CDT, regardless of the inputted time (if this is possible). thanks!

Comment: That's not how times zones work.  The user isn't in CST or CDT.  They're in CT.  The date and time itself is what determines whether CST or CDT is applicable.

Comment: Put another way, a person located in the USA's Central Time zone, as of right now (winter) observes Central Standard Time (UTC-6).  Last summer and next summer, they will observe Central Daylight Time (UTC-5).  It's not important which is in effect _now_, but only which is in effect on the date and time in question.